# Flutter dart generic constraint with some special keywords?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi everyone I'm newbie to dart but I have learn in C# for a while. Is there any generic constraint such as new() factory() in dart ?
(The factory() one is which limit the T has factory constructor)

```
class SuperDog<T is new(),factory()>

class Snoopy {

  factory Snoopy() {
    return ...
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you use the factory pattern in dart.   Generics are allowed.

```
Generics follow the pattern
class Cache<T> {
   final T _obj;
   Cache(this._obj);
   get value=> _obj;
}
Cache c=Cache<String>("Hello World")
debugPrint(c.value);
```

I demonstrate how to create a class factory in dart.

```
@JsonSerializable()
class EmployeeView {
  final int hrCo;
  final int employee;
  final String lastName;
  final String firstName;

  EmployeeView(
      this.hrCo,
      this.employee,
      this.lastName,
      this.firstName);

  factory EmployeeView.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$EmployeeViewFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$EmployeeViewToJson(this);
}
```

employeeView.g.dart    (builder_runner creates this code)

```
EmployeeView _$EmployeeViewFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
      return EmployeeView(
        json['hrCo'] as int,
        json['employee'] as int,
        json['lastName'] as String,
        json['firstName'] as String,
      );
    }

Map<String, dynamic> _$EmployeeViewToJson(EmployeeView instance) =>
    <String, dynamic>{
      'hrCo': instance.hrCo,
      'employee': instance.employee,
      'lastName': instance.lastName,
      'firstName': instance.firstName,
    };
```

run builder to generate you .g file.  you don't edit the g file

flutter pub run build_runner build

Comment: Thank you for your time. I'm wondering is there a constraint to limit the T must has a factory constructor?